# onPrepareOptionsMenu used in Android

Tags: java, android, menu

I want to use android menu function.
And I already set onPrepareOptionsMenu(),
and set the content.
But I have problem, that my pad has no menu icon to click.
Do I need to set anymore?

Comment: which version of android you are using and which version is your target sdk in your manifest file?

Comment: I set minSdkVersion="8"    android:versionCode="1"   android:versionName="1.0"

Comment: Is it under activity or fragment ?

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 3.0 (Honeycomb), that was made especially for tablets, there is no more hardware menu button (but phones still got one), so to use ActionBar for tablets, You could follow this tutorial:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/274639-android-actionbar-tutorial/

and read this too:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 1):

The [overflow option menu](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) icon (looks like 3 dots) at top-right corner will not appear if your device has a hardware menu key.

Your device must be at least on 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

In tablet you have implement ActionBar in your activity. For enable and use of ActionBar you must have to use Titlebar for your activity. Just create the Theme in style.xml having Title bar and store in value-xlarge dir for large screen. And get the ActionBar object by using this getActionBar().

Note: You must have to use API 11 or above if you have minSDK below 11 then you have check version of OS

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

> onPrepareOptionsMenu(),

which is for updating text and other thing once menu option is created,  use

> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu)

and selection of menuitem can be achieved by

> public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)

Many examples can be found for menu creation,updation and selection.

Comment: I can find the menu example, but my problem is that tablet has no menu button to click and call the onprepareoptionmenu() function. Tablet has home , back,..etc.. But no menu button.

Comment: May i know which tablet are you using, and what is it's android version

Comment: Here, it is i found article for you, which says that menu button not available on many device and also workaround for it [http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html]

Answer (score 0):

If you set `android:targetSdkVersion` bigger than 10 and you are using theme `NoTitleBar` in the devices which are running Android 3+ and which don't have menu button there won't show a software menu button next to back button. If you want that option to be enabled set your targetSdkVersion to 10 and test i your device if there will show the software menu button.